# makecab DDF file : space in destinationdir

Tags: cab

I'm making a .cab with makecab.exe /F but in my DDF file I'm referencing a directory that has a space in it.

```
.Set DestinationDir = site_event_templateListInstances\Files\Lists\RSVP List\
```

However, makecab doesn't recognise the space ad thinks the directory ends there. How can I make this work? I've tried quotations, but that doesn't work apparently.

Answer (score 0):

use the alternate short path

run cmd

```
cd "site_event_templateListInstances\Files\Lists\RSVP List\" 
command
```

you'll see the cmd promt gets decorated with the 8.3 alternative version of the requiered path; use that path

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `makecab.exe` has not a problem with spaces in folder names of `.Set`-Lines, but with the files in those folders; so `.Set DestinationDir = site_event_templateListInstances\Files\Lists\RSVP List\` will not cause a problem, but the line(s) `site_event_templateListInstances\Files\Lists\RSVP List\example.txt` will.

For me, putting quotes around those line(s) worked: `"site_event_templateListInstances\Files\Lists\RSVP List\example.txt"`